# mongodb v3.4 - wiredtiger - compact does not work

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I am using mongo v3.4.10 with WiredTiger. I run the following command:

```
db.runCommand({ compact: "my_collection" });
```

the response is:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

and the mongo log shows:

```
2017-10-31T00:12:20.282+0000 I COMMAND  [conn23] compact mydb.my_collection begin, options: paddingMode: NONE validateDocuments: 1
2017-10-31T00:12:21.662+0000 I COMMAND  [conn23] compact mydb.my_collection end
2017-10-31T00:12:21.663+0000 I COMMAND  [conn23] command mydb.my_collection appName: "MongoDB Shell" command: compact { compact: "my_collection" } numYields:0 reslen:22 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } } } protocol:op_command 1381ms
```

In short, everything looks fine, but the storageSize is exactly the same :/

I deleted lots of fields with a value of `null`, so I would expect a **significant** drop in disk usage.

I read online that early v3 had issues with this, but I'm on the latest version right now. The database is quite large so if I can avoid `repairDatabase` that would be good.

Any help is appreciated, thx.

---

UPDATE: I performed a mongodump / mongorestore, and it resulted in a 9% disk use reduction (admittedly I was expecting more). Nonetheless, it seems like compact *should* have had an impact.

UPDATE 2: I performed a repairDatabase and it had no effect. This is explicitly stated in mongo docs (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase):

> For WiredTiger, the operation rebuilds the database but does not result in the compaction of the collections in the database

but i thought i'd give it a crack. Still not sure why compact did nothing though.

Comment: null values don't take space basically in the collections and compression is taking care of those (null-value) keys.

Comment: @mils, Are you sure you have run the proper format db.runCommand(command). I mean to say that exact the command parameter in db.runCommand().

Comment: @JJussi null values don't take space in collection & that being handled by the compression is fine but the key itself will take some space. Right?
For e.g. `{ "name": null }` 
the key `name` will take space when stored in a bson document.

Answer (score 1):

@mils, The `compact` administration commands Rewrites and defragments all data and indexes in a collection. On WiredTiger databases, this command will release unneeded disk space to the operating system.

compact has the following form:

```
{ compact: <collection name> }
```

In you case after the `db.runCommand(command)` , you have got the message such as

```
{
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

it means your command has successfully executed.

On `WiredTiger`, `compact will rewrite the collection and indexes to minimize disk space by releasing unused disk space to the system`. This is useful if you have removed a large amount of data from the collection, and do not plan to replace it.

I am also attaching the `db.runCommand(command)` picture from mongo shell command,for proper format understanding of that command.

[image]

**WARNING:-**
*Always have an up-to-date backup before performing server maintenance such as the **compact operation**.*

**How to check the storage engine from the mongo command shell**

> db.serverStatus().storageEngine

**Note : -**
As per MongoDB BOL  the [WiredTiger Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/) From the `MongoDB version 3.2`: The `WiredTiger storage engine` is the **default storage engine** starting in **MongoDB 3.2**. For existing deployments, if you do not specify the `--storageEngine` or the storage.engine setting, `MongoDB 3.2` can `automatically determine the storage engine` used to create the data files in the `--dbpath` or [storage.dbPath](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath).

For further your ref [compact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/)